# crash on MainMenu.onCreateOptionsMenu

Tags: java, android, crash, oncreateoptionsmenu

When I test my app on Xiaomi A2, it runs fine. When I upload to Google Play, it crashes.
Stack Trace on Play console reads:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  at com.thongjoon.ocsc_exam_prep.MainMenu.onCreateOptionsMenu (MainMenu.java:29)
  at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu (Activity.java:4140)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu (FragmentActivity.java:2) ...
```

This happens after I migrate to AndroidX.

Here is my onCreateOptionsMenu

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_welcome, menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);
        mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(item);
        mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(getDefaultShareIntent());

       String isAvailable = getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.is_show_order);

        MenuItem buyItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_buy_sheets);
      //  if (isAvailable!=null) {
            if (!isAvailable.equals("yes")) {
                buyItem.setVisible(false);
            } else {
                buyItem.setVisible(true);
            }
    //    }

        return true;
    }
```

and

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
       int id = item.getItemId();
...
       if (id == R.id.action_buy_sheets) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
Uri.parse("https://forms.gle/1PYvktbuGPM3MScZ9")));
            return true;
        }
...
}
```

in build.gradle

```
...
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'

}
...
```

I use Analyze>Inspect Code to find error. No error reported.
I am new. This app is my first app.
Please help. Very much appreciated.

Comment: Which is the line 29 on MainMenu.java ?

Comment: import android.webkit.WebSettings; I set minifyEnabled  to true as suggested by the Play Console. Line 29 might be something else which I don't know.